# Identifier Class_name undefined C++ oop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am learning OOP through C++. And encountered with a dosen of errors. I managed to solve most of them, however this error is the biggest rock until now. Can you go over my code and tell me why VScode 2019 isn't seeing the class name? Although it is there in the header and in the implementation files.

Header: care.h

```
 #pragma once
 #include <string.h>
 #include <string>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;


  class care
  {

    int year;
    string color;
public:
    void setColor(string clr);
    void setYear(int yr);

    string getColor();
    int getYear();
 };
```

Implementaion file: care.cpp

```
 #include "care.h"
 #include <string>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;


 void care::setColor(string clr)
 {
     color = clr;
 }

 void care::setYear(int yr)
 {
    year = yr;
 }

 string care::getColor()
 {
     return color;
 }

 int care::getYear()
 {
    return year;
 }

 int care::getYear()
 {
     return year;;
 }
```

Client file:

```
 #include"care.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     cout << "Hello World!\n";
     care mine; //error is here at 'care' not recognizing it as a class in care.h, care.cpp

     mine.setColor("Red");
   return 0;
 }
```

The error message is:

> ```
> Error (active)  E0020   identifier "care" is undefined  11  C:\Users\AAROU\Documents\OOP\C++\11\11.cpp  9
> ```

Comment: Please show us the exact error message you got.

Comment: updated the question with the error message

Comment: Are you using VS? Is this copy-pasted error message, from the **output** window? Error List window doesn't show exact error messages.

Comment: the full one is ugly and unorganized. here it is howvere: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0020 identifier "care" is undefined 11 C:\Users\AAROU\Documents\OOP\C++\11\11.cpp 9

Comment: That looks like you copied from the Errors List again. The Output tab would not have anything about Severity Code.

Comment: @SanadAlArousi 1) "_the full one is ugly and unorganized_" No it isn't. I am always reading the errors from output window just fine. On the contrary: Error List errors lack necessary information, most of the time. 2) "_here it is howvere_" This is the same thing, as provided in the question.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? I don't think your code matches the error.

Comment: sorry but, where can i find the output window?

Comment: ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: There is no text above that?

Comment: Maybe the error message is a intellisense false positive.

Comment: no that is everything. though a moment ago it was giving me 1 failed not 0 failed

Comment: i switched to Build Only. now it disapeared. this is so wiered.

Comment: I think it was a problem / bug with Intellisense and not your code.

Comment: yeah after your comment i figured it out too. maybe the standard of the intellisense is high or it's a minor bug. thanks a lot. if you want to give a solution i will pick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with @drescherjm in the comments we both reached to a conclusion of intillesense having a bug/minor bug regarding my code.

I ran it and it gave me output before and after the class_name identifier. Also when I switched to BuildOnly window in the bottom rather than Build+Intillessence it ignored the error and gave 1 succeeded.

Sometimes the problem is with the computer, the compiler, or even some software surrounding the code. False Positive is indeed one of the most annoying errors.